# DB2 error code -991

Tags: sql, db2, return

I'm getting a return code of -991 upon running a db2 batch cobol program.
The program is attempting to fetch 65 rows within a cursor structure.
I cannot find anything on this particular error, does anyone know what it means ?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to look at the [db2 documentation](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2z9.doc/src/alltoc/db2z_09_prodhome.htm).

Error code -991 is [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2z9.doc.codes/src/tpc/n991.htm).

It says:

> -991
>   CALL ATTACH WAS UNABLE TO ESTABLISH AN IMPLICIT CONNECT OR OPEN TO DB2. RC1= rc1 RC2= rc2
>
> Explanation
>   Call attach attempted to perform an implicit connect and open as the result of an SQL statement. The connect or open failed with the returned values.
>   rc1
>   The value returned in FRBRC1 for the failed CONNECT or OPEN request.
>   rc2
>   The value returned in FRBRC2 for the failed CONNECT or OPEN request.
>   System action
>   The statement cannot be processed.
>
> Programmer response
>   Verify that the application intended to use the call attachment facility (CAF) as the mechanism to connect to DB2®. For functions or stored procedures running in the WLM-established stored procedure address space the application must be link-edited with or dynamically allocate the RRS attachment language interface module (DSNRLI), not CAF.
>
> SQLSTATE
>   57015

Hopefully that means something to you :)

Answer (score 0):

In case you're still stuck, my google-fu is strong.

SQLCODE  -991, Error: CALL ATTACH WAS UNABLE TO ESTABLISH AN IMPLICIT CONNECT OR OPEN TO DB2.  RC1= RC2=

From http://theamericanprogrammer.com/programming/sqlcodes.shtml